# Edge displaying .jpg image as randomly colored square

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, microsoft-edge

I have a problem that has just recently occurred, it may be a browser bug in Edge as I am sure it was working previously, but I have some .jpg images that are not showing in Edge (but show fine in IE, Chrome, Firefox) instead all I see is a color (different color for different image - even though there is no background color or any other color attributed - so should be white if image not showing - these images are using styles of radius and shadow, but removing them makes no difference.

When I right click and save image the correct jpg is downloaded, the link is good, as I say it works on other browsers, but no longer on edge (nothings changed that I know of). Any ideas?

as seen on Edge:

[image: images (or lack of) displayed by Edge]

As seen on other browsers:

[image: images as displayed on Chrome, IE and Firefox]

I have tried removing styles and checked the divs for overlaps or other common problems, everything looks OK.

```css
.sitelinks {
margin: 10px 42px 10px 45px;
padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
width: 180px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
}
.sitelinks:hover {
background: #CCC;
}
.sitelinks img {
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
box-shadow: 3px 5px 12px #000000;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.sitelinks img:hover {
-o-transform: scale(1.06);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.06);
-ms-transform: scale(1.06);
-moz-transform: scale(1.06);
transform: scale(1.06);
}
.desc {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 160px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.4em;
color: #333;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitelinks">
<a href="services.php" target="_self"><img id="link1" 
src="assets/img/services_ico.jpg" alt="Our Services"></a>
<div class="desc"><a href="services.php" target="_self">Our Services</a> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="sitelinks">
<a href="contact.php" target="_self"><img id="link2" 
src="assets/img/contact_ico.jpg" alt="Contact the team"></a>
<div class="desc"><a href="contact.php" target="_self">Contact Us</a></div>
</div>
<div class="sitelinks">
<a href="photos.php" target="_self"><img id="link3" 
src="assets/img/gallery_ico.jpg" alt="Picture Gallery"></a>
<div class="desc"><a href="photos.php" target="_self">Photo gallery</a> 
</div> 
</div>
<div class="sitelinks">
<a href="reviews.php" target="_self"><img id="link4" 
src="assets/img/feedback_ico.jpg" alt="Customer reviews"></a>
<div class="desc"><a href="reviews.php" target="_self">Customer 
testimonials and reviews</a></div>
</div>
```

There are four images that are the same html

Comment: What does Edge's developer console / DOM inspector show you?

Comment: Nothing unusual, but edge adds a width and height to the img tag even though its controlled by the css, stepping trough it everything seems fine but no jpg image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, Edge doesn't like the initial size of the jpeg set to 1px, increasing this value everything works as it did before - I dont know whats changed in Edge but I have set the initial size to 2px, and all is well.

Cheers for your help guys, my first time here, but wont be my last no doubt.

Comment: I suggest that you coud mark your answer as solution if it solved your problem, and this will be helpful for someone meets with the same problem.